# Regex: replace substring with condition

Tags: python, regex

I have text, it's example

```
[04.1_Filialy 680031, Khabarovsk Territory, Khabarovsk, ul. District, 6, building b, office 3.] and [04.1_OGRN660050463454]
```

Desire output

```
<address> 680031, Khabarovsk Territory, Khabarovsk, ul. District, 6, building b, office 3.<\address> and [04.1_OGRN660050463454]
```

I need if `re.findall(r'\[[\d\.]+_(?:Filialy|MN)[^]]+]` in str, replace first `r'\[[\d\.]+_(?:Filialy|MN)'` and r']' to `<address>` and `<\address>`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `[^]]+` in capturing group `()` and use `re.sub()`.

**Regex**: [`\[[\d\.]+_(?:Filialy|MN)([^]]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/BVW7Yo/1) Substitution: `<address>\1<\\address>`

**Python code**:

```
re.sub(r'\[[\d\.]+_(?:Filialy|MN)([^]]+)\]', r'<address>\1<\\address>', str)
```

Output:

```
<address> 680031, Khabarovsk Territory, Khabarovsk, ul. District, 6, building b, office 3.<\address> and [04.1_OGRN660050463454]
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/MhFKBE)